# counting the number of duplicates in the linked list Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to put the text file into a linkedlist and count how many duplicate words are in the linked list.

Here is my base code.

```
  public class Node{
        private Node next;
        private String data;
        private int Dup_Counter= 0;

        public Node(){
            this.next = null;
            this.data = data;
            this.Dup_Counter = 0;
        }
 public String fiile_Reader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("/Users/djhanz/IdeaProjects/datalab2/pg174.txt"); //reading a plain text file
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        String fileContent = ""; // initalizing an empty string to put scanned string text file

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            fileContent = fileContent.concat(scan.nextLine() + "\n"); // scan and put in into string object
        }
        fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", ""); // remove all the punctuation characters
        fileContent = fileContent.toLowerCase();
        return fileContent;
    }
    public void insert() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Node cursor = head;
        Single_LL Linked_L = new Single_LL();
        String file_content = Linked_L.fiile_Reader();
        String[] splitted_File = file_content.split(" ");

        for(int i=0 ; i<splitted_File.length; i++){
            Linked_L.add(splitted_File[i]);
        }
    }
    public int Word_Counter(String word){
        String compare =word;
        Node cursor = head;
        int counter = 0;
        while(cursor!=null){
            if (cursor.data.equals(compare)){
                counter++;

            }
            cursor = cursor.next;
        }
        return counter;
    }
    public void Dup_Count(){
        Node cursor = head.next;
        while (cursor != null){
            if(head.data == cursor.data){
                head.Dup_Counter++;
                break;
            }
            cursor = cursor.next;
            System.out.println(cursor.Dup_Counter);
        }
        head = head.next;

    }
    public String dup_num(){
        Node cursor = head;
        String rtn = "";
        while (cursor!= null){
            if(cursor.Dup_Counter > 20 ){
                rtn += cursor.data + " -> ";
            }
            cursor = cursor.next;

        }
        return rtn;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Program1 test = new Program1();
        String file_content = test.fiile_Reader();
        Single_LL Linked_L = new Single_LL();
        String[] splitted_File = file_content.split(" ");
        int spli_len = splitted_File.length;
        for(int i =0; i< spli_len; i++){

            Linked_L.add(splitted_File[i]);
        }
```

My approach is that I added anthoer variable in Node Class called dup_counter.
Function Dup_Count() is looping through the linked list and when it sees that duplicate it updates the Node's dup_counter variable.

I'm trying to find words that appeared more than 20 times and dup_num() is my approach to do this. Looping through the linkedlist and if the Node's dup_counter is more than 20 add it to the string and return it. However, Dup_Count() is not in fact updating the dup_count value. Insertion worked fine but I can't seem to find what is wrong with my dup_counter. Can someone please help me fix the bug?

Comment: You actually called `Dup_Count()` somewhere?

Comment: yes, it doesn't show in my code but I called it when I was testing in my main method.

Comment: The reason I ask is that, near as I can tell, calling `Dup_Count()` destroys the list, because it modifies `head`.  Every call will lop one item from the front of the list; call it enough times and the list will just disappear!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to simplify your task using a Map as follows

Somehow get all of the words into a collection `Collection<String> words`. This should be easy to do using the reader code you already have.

Now, to count the number of occurrences of each word, we can use a Map:

```
Map<Integer, Long> counter = words.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p, Collectors.counting()));
```

Now you wanted to find all of the words that occurred more than 20 times, you could evaluate

```
Set<String> wordsOccuringManyTimes = counter
       .entrySet().stream()
       .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 20)
       .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

And if you wanted to get the total sum of all duplicates, you could simply evaluate

```
int duplicateCount = counter.values().stream().mapToInt(x -> x - 1).sum();
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer but I'm not allowed to use Map

Comment: I see. Good luck.